# A strange "No module named 'XX' " problem

Tags: python

I know how to import a package or module, but I meet a quite strange problem.

If I run `swmm5_extend_function/example.py`, everything is fine. However, when I run `example.py`,  errors occur:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "example.py", line 2, in <module>
    from swmm5_extend_function.Swmm5Extend import SWMM5ReadInp   
File "C:\project\swmm5_extend_function\Swmm5Extend.py", line 1, in <module>
    import swig.SWMM5ReadInpFile as swmm 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'swig'
```

Here is my project structure:

```
project/     
-- example.py   
-- ......   
-- swmm5_extend_function/  
      -- __init__.py
      -- example.py
      -- Swmm5Extend.py
      -- swig/
           -- __init__.py
           -- SWMM5ReadInpFile.py
           -- ....
```

Here is code of each .py file:

swmm5_extend_function/Swmm5Extend.py

```
import swig.SWMM5ReadInpFile as swmm

class SWMM5ReadInp(object):
    pass
```

swmm5_extend_function/example.py

```
from Swmm5Extend import SWMM5ReadInp
```

example.py

```
from swmm5_extend_function.Swmm5Extend import SWMM5ReadInp
```

I want to know why this strange error happens.

Comment: `swig/` is in the same folder as `swmm5_extend_function/example.py`, but not `example.py`.

Comment: Change `import swig.SWMM5ReadInpFile as swmm` to `import swmm5_extend_function.swig.SWMM5ReadInpFile as swmm`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: you're probably running the command from the `/project/` folder. If that's the case, you're calling 2 different `example.py` files.

Comment: @Gsk Yes, so my question is why the error occurs only when I am calling example.py. Both "example.py" and "swmm5_extend_function/example.py" can reach Swmm5Extend.py, but only example.py will report a error.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks for you relpy! I know what you mean, but how can I improve my code to solve this problem? I think the link below cannot solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a better explanation, I've created the following folder structure:

```
test/     
-- __init__.py
-- greeter.py # Greets in German
-- subfolder/  
    -- __init__.py
    -- greeter.py # Greets in Italian
    -- test.py
    -- deepfolder/
        -- __init__.py
        -- greeter.py # Greets in France
```

As you may notice, we have 3 files with the same name, each one greets in a different language using a function with the same name. The only function in a `greeter.py` file is:

```
def says():
    print("Hello World!")
```

**IMPORT FROM THE SAME FOLDER**
If from `test.py` file we import `greeter` and run the `says` function, we'll have:

```
import greeter as greeter

greeter.says()
```

**Output:**

```
Buongiorno Mondo! # Italian output
```

**IMPORT FROM A SUBFOLDER**
But what if we want to import from a subfolder?
To import from a subfolder (i.e., `deepfolder/`), we simply add an empty `__init__.py` file into the folder, then we can specify the path in the import:

```
import deepfolder.greeter as greeter

greeter.says()
```

**Output:**

```
Bonjour le Monde! # France output
```

**IMPORT FROM A PARENT FOLDER**
At last, you may want to import from a parent folder.
You should try to have your `main` running file at the top of the folder tree, but things happens and you find yourself looking to import a module from a parent folder.
For doing this, you need to add the parent folder to the sys.path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/dir")
from test import greeter as greeter

greeter.says()
```

**Output:**

```
Guten Morgen Welt! # German output
```

Importing scripts and modules isn't really the most pythonic way to solve things, you may want to have a look on [Python's documentation about packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

**TL;DR**
In your `project/example.py` use

```
import swmm5_extend_function.swig.SWMM5ReadInpFile as swmm
```

instead of

```
import swig.SWMM5ReadInpFile as swmm
```